# Python: Loop to reference one line of code until conditions are met

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to build a list from the users input until they say "yes". I have made it as far as I show below but then soon realize I will have to continue to write a line a code for as many times as I wanted to allow the user to input. But the idea is to let the user build a list of numbers until they are annoyed with doing so, so that I can reference it later in the program. So essentially I would like to reference line 6 until "yes" is met.

```
play_num = int
play_num = input('Give me a number.')
play_num = int(play_num) + int(1)
choice1 = str
AnnoyList = []
choice1 = input ("You said " + str(play_num) + " right? ")
if (choice1.lower is "no"):
    AnnoyList.append(play_num)
    play_num = input ("Oh, sorry what was it then? ")
    AnnoyList.append(play_num)
if (choice1.lower is "yes")
```

Comment: Why won't a loop work here?

Comment: Did you miss the bottom half of your code? `if (choice1.lower is "yes")` will give you a syntax error.

Comment: You must learn about loops before attempting to solve this problem. Loops are quintessential to computer programming. You cannot (and should not) learn about them by asking a question on SO.

Comment: I won't lie, I am very new to Python, and programming in general, I just couldn't figure a way to make it work in my head. I had thought about while loops as some users mentioned below. Just didn't think I was on the right track. No, its not missing, I hadn't wrote it because I knew the method I had written what was above would never pass, so I was working on that problem first.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `while` loops. Set a variable equal to `True` and loop until the user enters no, then set it to `False`.

Or, if you know how many times you want to loop, look into `for` loops.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: Thank you for the link to the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Use while loops with a break statement when the user enters `yes`. Read about them here: [Control Flow Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Your code will look like this

```
AnnoyList = []
choice1 = "no"
play_num = input('Give me a number.')
while choice1.lower()!="yes":# notice the parenthesis

    play_num = int(play_num) + (1)
    choice1 = input ("You said " + str(play_num) + " right? ")
    if (choice1.lower() == "no"):
         AnnoyList.append(play_num)
         play_num = input ("Oh, sorry what was it then? ")
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much, that clears up how to use while loops for me a lot!